# Unable to Load unload styles in my Aurelia app

Tags: aurelia

I need a solution to **load/unload styles** in my Aurelia app. This is because I have a special main.css for my 'public' root app and another admin.css for my 'private' (admin) root app. (Yes, 2 roots in my app). These css are not `compatible` one with each other.

I found a plugin named [aurelia-useable-style-loader](https://github.com/jbockle/aurelia-useable-style-loader). I try to integrate it in my Aurelia application as explained in the readme. At runtime, I can see `[aurelia-useable-style-loader] begin configure` and 
`[aurelia-useable-style-loader] end configure` in my console but css files are not loaded/unloaded. So something go wrong and I don't know what.

One thing I pointed is that my Aurelia app is based on the Aurelia CLI / Typescript / SystemJS as bundler. While the plugin is based on Webpack. Maybe the 2 are not compatible ?

Steps I did:

- npm install aurelia-useable-style-loader
- then use the plugin in main.ts:

  > aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-useable-style-loader');
- then added one reference in my aurelia.json:

  > "aurelia-useable-style-loader",

Tha's all. At runtime, no particular errors, but css are not loaded/unloaded.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

PS: as a workaround, I proceed differently (see below) but I'm curious to do it with the plugin *aurelia-useable-style-loader*

```
this.masterStyleSheetLoaded = true;
this.httpClient.fetch('./src/css/main.css')
   .then((data) => data.text())
   .then((styles) => {
        DOM.injectStyles(styles, null, null, 'masterStylesheet');
        this.masterStyleSheetLoaded = true;
   });
```

Comment: The plugin uses `webpack style-loader/useable` in order to work, but you are using `System` as a bundler. I think this is the problem (as you suggested yourself in the question)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It is too bad this plugin (Webpack) is not compatible with SystemJs. Now I understand better.